# Is my proof that $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \log(\frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2})$ diverges correct?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

So I'm in Real Analysis and right now we are discussing series. It's very interesting. There is a problem on my homework that I want to make sure I used the comparison test correctly for. Keep in mind we haven't proved derivatives, so we can't use L'Hopital's rule or any of that fancy stuff. We can use only the series tests and rigorous definition of limits of sequences ($|a_n - L| < \epsilon $). So here's the problem :

> Decide if the series
>   $$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \log \left(\frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2}\right)$$
>   converges or diverges. If it converges, find its value.

Here's my work: take $a_n = \log \left(\frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2}\right)$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

$$\log \left(\frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2}\right) > \frac{1}{n}$$
take both sides to the power $e$

$$\frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2} > e^\frac{1}{n} \iff n^2+n+1 > e^\frac{1}{n} \cdot n^2$$

And this is true because $1 \leq e^\frac{1}{n}\leq e$ and $n^2+n+1 > n^2$. 
And we know $\frac{1}n$ diverges and $b_n$ is less than $a_n$, so $a_n$ also diverges.

Q.E.D.

Comment: Sorry :( I though the link could just be copied and pasted. I'm very sorry.

Comment: This would be much easier to read if you were to properly format your question using MathJax.  If click on the link to edit your post, there is an easily findable link for help.

Comment: I think that your solution to the problem is correct. If I understand well, you use the comparison test with $$\ln(\frac{n^2+n+1}{n^2}) > 1/n$$

Comment: I'm sorry to everyone for my poor formatting. I just recently made this account and am new to the website. I guess I skipped past the MathJax part. I'll edit and make it more clear. 

Sorry.

Comment: @Crostul You are correct. That's what I wanted to show. Thank you.

Comment: My edit was for formatting only. Use \iff for logical equivalence, not =. (And \implies for $\implies$.) And \log  for log... (Also  \ln for ln,) And \leq for =<. (And  \geq for =>.) And \cdot is preferable to an asterisk for "times".....  Your proof is flawed:  $1\leq e^{\frac {1}{n}}\leq e\implies$ $  n^2\leq n^2e^{\frac {1}{n}}\leq n^2e,$, but $n^2e$ is GREATER than $n^2+n+1$ for $n\geq 2.$

Comment: I see this but I was comparing $e^\frac{1}n*n^2$ to $n^2+n+1$ in the long run. As n goes to infinity, $e^\frac{1}n$ would go to 1, and so $n^2 + n + 1$ > $e^\frac{1}n*n^2$ for n very large.

Comment: It is true that $n^2+n+1>n^2e^{1/n}$ for $n\geq 2$ but not for the reasons you have given. Consider that $n^2+n+1/3<n^2e^{1/n}$ for $n\geq 2.$ What happens if you replace $n^2+n+1$ with $n^2+n+1/3$ in your argument?

Comment: Oh you're right. I see what you're saying. How would I go about fixing this error? I can't really think of a way to prove the statement. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To show that $\sum_n \log \frac {n^2+n+1}{n^2}$ diverges by the most elementary means:

$$\text {We have }\quad a_n=\log \left(\frac {n^2+n+1}{n^2}\right)>\log \left( \frac {n^2+n}{n^2}\right)=\log  \left( \frac {n+1}{n}\right).$$ $$\text {Therefore }\quad \sum_{n=1}^Na_n>\sum_{n=1}^N\log \left(\frac {n+1}{n}\right)=$$ $$=\log \prod_{n=1}^N\left(\frac {n+1}{n}\right)=\log \left(\frac {(N+1)!/1!}{N!}\right)=\log \;(N+1).$$

Comment: We haven't learned or used the infinite product series yet. But I believe this still helps as $log (\frac{n+1}{n}) = log (n+1) - log (n)$. And then we have a telescoping series where eventually $S_N = log (n+1)$ and therefore diverges. Was my previous method incorrect? And thank you for the help,